# Lower bound for prime number function $\pi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

Let $x$ be a real number and $\pi(x): \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{P}$ be the function defined as

$$\pi(x)=\#\{p\le x:p \mbox{ is prime}\}$$
(that is, $\pi(x)$ outputs the number of prime numbers immediately preceding and including $x$). E.g., $\pi(2)=1$, $\pi(10) = 4$, etc.

> **Theorem**: For $x\ge 2$, we have $\pi(x)\ge \log(\log x)$.
>
> **Proof**: We first note that the result holds for $2\le x < 4$.

*My comment*: How can one immediately see this if not by taking the derivative of $\log(\log x))$? But since $\log$ is an increasing function, shouldn't we be able to say immediately that this result holds not just for $2\le x<4$, but for $2\le x <\infty$?

> For $x\ge 4$, let $s\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy
>
> $$2^{2^s}\le x\le 2^{2^{s+1}}$$
>
> [We already know from a proposition that the upper bound for $p_s$ is $2^{2^s}$]. We have that $x\ge 2^{2^s}\le p_s$, thus $\pi(x)\ge s$. By taking logarithms twice, we get:
>
> $$x\le 2^{s+1}\implies \log x \le 2^{s+1} \log 2$$
>   so that 
>   $$\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log2}\right)}{\log 2}< s+1$$
>
> It follows that
>
> $$\pi(x)\ge s > \frac{\log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\right)}{\log 2}-1\ge \log(\log x)$$

*My comment*: I'm not quite sure how to prove the last inequality.

One can show that

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log 2}\right)}{\log 2}-1=\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log x}{2\log 2}\right)}{\log 2}$$

But $2\log 2 > 1$, thus $\log\left(\frac{\log x}{2\log 2}\right)<\log \log x$.

Would appreciate some clarifications for my comments.

Comment: I posted a way to get a cheap lower bound for $\pi (x)$, but I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.  unless I am confused (always possible) the cheap one I produce is still stronger than the one you want.  But are we even speaking of the same $\pi (x)$ ?  I agree with your first definition, but not the second one.  For instance, $\pi(8)=4$ because the primes $≤8$ are $\{2,3,5,7\}$.  But the largest prime less than $8$ is $7$.

Comment: To stress:  you need to clarify the definition of $\pi (x)$.  The first thing you defined is standard.  $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes $p≤ x$.  But that function is not prime valued (despite what you wrote) and it is obviously not equal to the largest prime $≤ x$.

Comment: Worth remarking, I suppose, that the largest prime $≤x$ is certainly never less than $\pi(x)$.

Comment: In my understanding, $\pi(x)$ is a function that outputs a prime number less than or equal to $x$. But maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Well, that is not the standard definition.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  But look up what it is you intended.  My posted solution refers to the standard definition, which indeed is the first definition you give.  But maybe you meant something completely different.

Comment: I only gave one definition, but it is probably incorrect (unfortunately, I had never seen this kind of set notation before, so I didn't recognize the definition). I'll edit my question now.

Comment: Yes $\pi(x) =\#\{p\le x\} = \sum_{p \le x} 1$

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a way to get a cheap lower bound.

Note that any $n≤x$ can be written uniquely  as $m\times k^2$ where $m$ is square free.  It follows that $$x≤ 2^{\pi(x)}\sqrt x\implies \sqrt x ≤ 2^{\pi(x)}\implies \frac {\log_2(x)}2≤\pi(x)$$ This seems better than your desired bound.

Comment: I'm not sure how it follows that $x\le 2^{\pi(x)}\sqrt x$ from what you've written.

Comment: If you have $A = \pi(x)$ primes you can generate $2^A$ square-free numbers. Plus the $\sqrt{x}$ different possible values for $k^2$ you can generate $2^A \sqrt{x}$ numbers, but you need to generate $x$ numbers to attain $x$, thus $2^A \sqrt{x} \ge x$ @sequence

Comment: @sequence  do you understand what  user reuns wrote?  By definition, there are $\pi(x)$ primes $≤x$ and any square free number can be defined uniquely by telling me which of these are included.  Of course many such products are larger than $x$ so this is a very crude bound.

Comment: @lulu Unfortunately I don't see how it follows that one can generate $2^A$ square-free numbers, and why we need $2^A$ square-free numbers. Also, it's not clear how $\sqrt{x}$ is relevant.

Comment: I am counting expressions of the form $m\times k^2$ less than $x$ where $m$ is square free.  Well, not counting, just trying to find an upper bound for the count.  There are $\sqrt x$ ways to choose $k^2$ (obviously) and there are fewer than $2^{\pi(x)}$ ways to choose $m$  (for each subset of the primes $≤ x$ let $m$ be the product of those primes).

Comment: But please clarify the definition you want for $\pi(x)$.  As I have pointed out, you give two and they are not consistent.

Comment: Can you please clarify? 1. Why do you need to count expressions to find a lower bound? 2. It's not obvious that there are $\sqrt{x}$ ways to choose $k^2$ (and why do we need to choose them at all?), since $\sqrt{x}$ is not an integer in general. 3. How do you know that there are $2^{\pi(x)}$ ways to choose $m$?
I think this is all very confusing, so it would probably be much easier to work with my questions about the proof.

Comment: You are certainly free to do that.  But, I repeat, as you appear to be unsure as to what you mean by $\pi(x)$ you should clarify that before anything else.

Comment: I've clarified it above.